# Varswap Basis - What is it in practice?

Tags: volatility, swaps

What is the varswap basis?  I am not completely sure what this number represents.  Is it the basis between the estimated future realized volatility and the vol surface implied volatilty at a specified tenor?

Comment: Where do you see that term? Is it in a paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variance swap basis is the basis between theoretical value of the variance strip and the actual strikes traded in the brokers' market.

Comment: I'll ask you the same question that the OP was supposed to answer: Where is this term used? Where is it published?

Comment: Any time you are trying to buy a var swap in the IBD or from a market-maker, you will hear of it. It's not really published anywhere as a piece of market data, but it's fairly easy to calculate historically if you have broker markets for variance swaps. The term is an industry standard.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Your comment should be part of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever it is, it clearly is not a common term of art in the industry.  Three possibilities come to mind:

1. **To the options:** Since one can (under certain assumptions about continuity etc) synthesize a variance swap from European option contract prices, the basis may represent the difference between varswap price and the synthesized price.
2. **To the VIX:** If we are talking about SPX variance swaps there is a convexity-related basis to the VIX futures.
3. **To another tenor:** As with futures, there is a calendar basis in variance swaps.